# JqPlot crashes jQuery mobile JS

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jqplot

I'm running an jqPlot Diagram on a jquery mobile Page.
The diagrams page is a subsite from mainpage.
Mainpage has several Links to other subpages.
Subpages has no other subpages under themselves.

When i navigate from Main Page to the Diagrams Page, it looks fine.
When i no use the Back Button (jQuery Mobile's one in Header, not Browser Navigation), the MainPage is shown again. At this Point jQuery mobile seems crashing, no links are working anymore. Page is freezed.

I will post some code later.

Maybe anyone had the same Problem before?
Does anybody has got an idea?

Comment: Are any errors displayed in the browser console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found out, that this seems to be a common Problem. The jqPlot js is going to crash all ajax requests for some reasons.

[Loading Json data into jqPlot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535680/problem-with-json-and-jqplot?rq=1)
and
[jqplot conflict with jquerymobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397651/jqplot-conflict-with-jquerymobile?rq=1)

There is a little workaround, but infact it is not solved completely.